# Why does this not work? MySQL (TRYING TO MAKE A WHITELIST UPDATE)

Tags: mysql

Trying to make a whitelist system with the arguments below, but It is not echoing anything. The code is not function as it should atm. The problem is that it is not updating it. This is the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "premium";
$key = $_GET["key"];
$user = $_GET["user"];
$id = $_GET["id"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `whitelists` WHERE `key` = '$key'");


if( $result === false ) {
    echo 'nope';
}
    else
{
    echo 'yes';
    mysqli_query("UPDATE `whitelists` SET `id` = '$id', `user` = '$user' WHERE `key` ='$key' ");

}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing you should do is Use mysqli_* functions or PDO, because your code is Deprecated.

example:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE whitelists SET `id` = '$id', `user` = '$user' WHERE `key` ='$key' ");
```

Secondly you should use a false statement instead of num_rows.

```
if($result === false)
{
    echo "nope";
}
    else
{
    // Execute your query here.
}
```

Comment: I am now getting "nope" echo'd whilst the key is in the db. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you do this?
if($result === false)
{
echo nope;
}
?

Comment: Yes, I did do everything.
Do you have Discord so, we could talk easier?

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code, then i can help u more.

Comment: I have updated the question, but I am not sure if anything - much has changed that could have this impact on the database not finding the row, because when I try it in phpMyAdmin, I can find it.

Comment: then you made a mistake above the if statement, becase what ever happens, without error the code will always echo something. did you echo something in the else?

Comment: Yes I echo something in the else, and nothing has changed above.... I will check again.

Comment: use 3 times = between $result and false.

Comment: Works now, but it is not updating in the database.

Comment: print all your values,  and make sure there are no mistakes in the sql, does it work in the sql terminal of phpmyadmin?

Comment: Printing values, works.
Mistakes in the SQL. (dont think i have any)
phpMyAdmin. Works

Comment: did you try the sql here? http://localhost/phpmyadmin/server_sql.php, insert your sql from your code and just edit the values from the vaiables.

Comment: ima recreate this with database and php file, but i need some time.

Comment: I am thinking, is this all your code, do you even connect to a database with php?

Comment: can you try my new edit, i think mysqli needs a database link inside the query

Comment: @Technoo-_, np bro, dont forget to close the question.